# Converting an integer scale to another integer within given range

Tags: java, hash, int, range

I would like to distribute a set of given integers to be scaled down to another integer within a given specified range, lower of that being 0, in fastest possible computation. Idea is to distribute the numbers into a small finite set of pockets and evenly distributed keeping consistent mapping of one given number will always go to same pocket.

Say, I have numbers in he range [1000000, 9999999] and I would distribute them to the extent uniformly within a scaled down range say [0, 30] in a way that a given number 88888888 always map to the same number e.g. say 22 and so on. Another number 777777777 may also map to 22, but should be consistent. A number 888000888 may map to a different number within the range e.g 25.

If I call the function as scale(int num, int range), the converted value would be `[0, range - 1]`.
A naive converter could be using a remainder method, e.g.

```
int scale(int num, int range) {
   return num % range;
}
```

Can any other method e.g. bit operation could scale this number within the given range to make it real fast?
The code example is in Java, but, in theory, could be any language.

Comment: You need to explain what properties you want the mapping to have.

Comment: it is not clear what you are seeking. At the moment, an answer like "return 0" will be valid.

Comment: If you limit range to be powers of 2 you could use a bitwise and, but you need to specify more constraints and explain what you want to use the mapping for.